# Tipsy Jquery plugin won't load inside another Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tipsy

I'm working with a the JQuery tipsy plugin and I can get it to work fine on my normal php page but when I run data from XML thru another javascript it's not loading or working properly... I've tried every imaginable change/variable and I'm stuck.

All my jquery & jquery.tipsy scripts are linked correctly because it works outside of this JS.

```
    $(function() {
    $('.instructions').tipsy({gravity: 's'});
});
```

Then when I call it inside the other JS it won't show at all:

```
 return "<table cellpadding='8' cellspacing='0'><tr>" +
"<tr>" +
"<td class='mn'>" + vs.manualName + "</td>" +
"<td><a class='instructions' href='#' title='" + vs.manInstr + "'>Instructions</a></td>" +
"<td class='sku'>" + vs.skuNum  "</td>" +
"</tr></table>"
};
```

Do I have to write it out in the JS for the tipsy to see it?

Comment: Are you trying to call the plugin `tipsy` on the element `.instructions` before `.instructions` exists on the page?

Comment: Nope. I thought that but I put the tipsy function in every place... before, after, and evne inside the other JS... ahaha. Nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that by the time the Tipsy is fired, the `.instructions` are already loaded and inside the DOM. So after the `data from XML thru another javascript` is loaded, execute.

```
    $('.instructions').tipsy({gravity: 's'});
```